# How to use LessHat Mixin with variable for URL?

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm trying to create a mixin like this:

```
.bgMixer(@image) {
  .gradient(~"url('@{image}') no-repeat center bottom, linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)");
}
```

(.gradient is a [LessHat](http://lesshat.com) mixin)

The result is not what you would expect (there's no image)

[Here's my Codepen](http://codepen.io/gilbox/pen/Kjmxl) where you can try to fix it.

Comment: What less compiler do you use? This code is correct and lessc/less.js 1.4.x...1.5.x compile this code just fine. Notice that your codepen snippet is also compiled w/o any error (though the image is not visible for some reason, the CSS result seems to be OK)

Comment: So we probably need more details about your building environment and less files used (at least the file/lines the error points to) to be able to help. As I already mentioned above the codepen.io (which uses 1.4.2 too if I'm not mistaken) compiles your snippet without errors. So it looks like the problem is not in this particular line of the code but somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, I'm changing the question to why doesn't this code pen work?

Comment: Ah, I see now what is wrong with it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that LessHat's `.gradient` is implemented via `background-image` property hence you can't use `no-repeat center bottom` there. You need to set these values via corresponding properties (`backround-postion` etc.).